# How do I write "I'm sleeping" in French?

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical

Is it "Je dors" or  is it "Je vais dormir"?  What's the difference?  Which one is accurate?

Comment: *Je dors* means *I'm sleeping*. *Je vais dormir* means *I'm going to bed / to sleep*.

Comment: Theoretically, it shouldn't be possible for you to say that :).

Comment: Actually, yes: *- Que fais-tu demain à 4h du matin ? - A quatre heures ? Je dors !* :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'm sleeping* actually means *je dors*. *Je vais dormir* would be *I am going to sleep*.

[This page](http://www.mycow.eu/cours-anglais.php?id=115) shows how to translate English simple and continuous present into French. 
It is an English exercise for French speakers but it is an interesting exercise to use it as an English speaker.

Comment: This is correct. But in spoken French, you can say pretty much anything. Like « Je suis fatigué, allez je dors » meaning  "I'm off to sleep."

Comment: @PatrickT That's true! I forgot that while answering.